# Trouble with TextField and new line

Tags: android, text, textfield, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose, and I've an issue with `TextField` :
When I want to insert a new line, the `onValueChange` send me a wrong string value.

Few steps to illustrate :

```
// Step 1
currentValue : ""
input value : "A"
onValueChange : "A" // OK

// Step 2
currentValue : "A"
input value : "\n"
onValueChange : "A\n" // OK

// Step 3
currentValue : "A\n"
input value : "B"
onValueChange : "AB\n" // Here the "B" isn't inserted at the end, why ?

// Step 4
currentValue : "AB\n"
input value : "C"
onValueChange : "AB\nC" // The "C" is correctly inserted
```

I'm using a `BasicTextField`, but I've the same bug with `TextField` :

```kotlin
var message by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
BasicTextField(
    value = message,
    onValueChange = { message = it },
    textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp),
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->

        if (message.isEmpty())
            Text(text = "Enter message")

        innerTextField()
    }
)
```

Anyone else faces with that issue ?

**EDIT: Possible source found**

In my test I've that issue with a Xiaomi Mi8 with a Android 10 custom ROM, but with my S21U (Android 11 official), I've no issue.

It's maybe because of the custom ROM or Android 10.

**EDIT2: Bug track**

This issue is now known by Google, they work on a fix:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193457105

Comment: Which Compose version are you using?
I copied and paste your code and it's working for me on rc-01...

Comment: @nglauber I’m using rc01 too, but I had the same issue in beta09

Answer (score 0):

Try removing that `decorationBox` parameter. Never seen such behaviour before really